Can Typescript infer subtypes of parameters based on a dynamic variable accessing an object-literal with functions with a common parameter supertype?
I apologize for the most likely inappropriate terminology to describe the following issue.
I am trying to implement a sort of "functional Strategy-Pattern" with an object literal in Typescript to avoid if-else-cascades or switch-statements. The "strategies" have different parameter types, that are derived from a common interface. When a "strategy" is selected with a dynamic variable from the object literal that holds all strategies, an error occurs, as typescript can't infer the appropriate subtype for the parameter each function requires.
The error-message I get is Argument of type 'FunctionConfig' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. The intersection 'Function1Config & Function2Config' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents. Type 'Function1Config' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
I think I understood why Typescript can't possibly infer the type, as no explicit connection exists between the specific property of the subtypes, the dynamic variable to access the object literal and the keys of the object literal itself.
Is there any way I can direct typescript to infer the types with object literals, or do I need to resort to Type-Guards (if-else-cascades) of some form?
interface FunctionConfig {
  type: string
}
interface Function1Config extends FunctionConfig {
  type: "func1";
  propertySpecificToFunc1: "something";
}
interface Function2Config extends FunctionConfig {
  type: "func2";
  propertySpecificToFunc2: "somethingElse";
}

function someFunction(functionConfig: Function1Config) {}
function someOtherFunction(functionConfig: Function2Config) {}

const FunctionLookUp = {
  func1: someFunction,
  func2: someOtherFunction
};

const FunctionExecution = (functionKey: "func1" | "func2", functionConfig: FunctionConfig) => {
  const result = FunctionLookUp[functionKey](functionConfig); // error occurs here!
}


You're trying to use correlated unions as described in ms/TS#30581 and the recommended approach is to refactor to generics as described in ms/TS#47109. Using that technique with your example looks like this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thanks for the quick answer and the references. Works like a charm!
